# Problem with visual studio code(terminal powershell

Tags: powershell

I have problem with my Integrated terminal power shell in VSC.
I don't can nothing writing in terminal. Cursus not Working. I don't see any path to folder. Nothing.
Help.

| |

I uninstalling my VSC and reistaling

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.